# How do I use the other elevators?

Tags: let-it-die

I noticed a red elevator symbol in Wanoki (floor 2) and a dark green elevator symbol in Uge (floor 15), but I can't use the elevator on either of these floors. What do they do? They aren't part of the main elevator that is attached to the lobby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just discovered a second dark red elevator in Shimo-Omeno (floor 10), I was given the option to ride the elevator to Wanoki (floor 2).

Thus, it looks like the alternate elevators work the same as the main elevator, but with less stops. Also, you cannot access these elevators from the lobby area.